# adding 'curl' command to sinatra and rails?

Tags: ruby, curl

(GAVE UP ON INSTALLING CURB. POSTED NEW QUESTION PER SUGGESTION OF ONE OF THE RESPONDENTS)
I thought 'curl ' was 'built-in' but got an undefined method error in a sinatra app. is there a gem i need to add?

Same question for rails 3?

---

The application is that I have to simply 'hit' an external url (http://kickstartme.someplace.com?action=ACTIONNAME&token=XYZXYZXYZ) to kickstart a remote process.

the external url returns XML describing success/failure in the format:

```
<session>
  <success>true</success>
  <token>xyzxyzxyz</token>
  <id>abcabcabc</id>
</session>
```

So really, ALL I need is for my rails and sinatra apps to hit that url and parse whatever is returned AND grcefully handle the remote server failing to reply.

Comment: Why not describe the bigger problem you are trying to solve? curl is a nice tool, but it isn't the only solution in Ruby for HTTP connectivity. There are other modules built into Ruby, such as Net/HTTP or Open-URI, that makes HTTP simple, or gems like HTTPClient and Typhoeus that handle multithreaded connections or HTTParty that makes it easy to add a HTTP client to a class.

Comment: excellent point. thank you. edited per your suggesiton.

Comment: Open-URI is the perfect tool to do that. If you need to parse the returned XML then look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
response = open("http://kickstartme.someplace.com?action=ACTIONNAME&token=XYZXYZXYZ").read
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response)
```

Comment: Add `require 'nokogiri'` in your require list, and `doc = Nokogiri::XML(response)` and the OPs needs would be met.

Comment: happy to help. @jpwynn, hope it helps. Feel free to ask for help if you run into any Nokogiri questions. It's a nice parser but parsing can get confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), a Ruby binding to libcurl. You will get all the curl features without having to shell out with `system`.

```
curl -b "auth=abcdef; ASP.NET_SessionId=lotsatext;" example.com
```

turns into

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://example.com/')
curl.cookies = 'auth=abcdef; ASP.NET_SessionId=big-wall-of-text;'
curl.perform
```

[More curb examples](https://github.com/taf2/curb/tree/master/samples)

Comment: I'm using windows xp for my dev box, giut-bask. have DevKit installed and have never had trouble installing gems. (if they need to be built, devkit modifies the path automatically). but it fails $ gem install curb
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.

Comment: the curb docs say you need libcurl first. the libcurl docs say you need curb or curl-multi. trying 'gem install curb-multi' fails with same message as trying 'gem install curb'

Comment: my system (using gitbash) DOES have curl installed... curl --verison returns: curl 7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3